# EF4.1 Eager loaded linked objects are returned null

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4, eager-loading

Can anyone explain why a Company is returned but Company.CompanyServices is null (even though I've created one in the test)?

```
        public List<Company> GetContactCompanies(int contactId)
        {
          var query = (
                        from directorCompany in ctx.CompanyDirectors
                          .Where(d => d.ContactAddress.Contact.Id == contactId)
                          .Include(d => d.Company.CompanyServices)
                        select directorCompany.Company
                      ).OrderBy(c => c.CompanyName).Distinct();
          return query.ToList();
        }
```

Note substituting the Include for `.Include("Company.CompanyServices")` has no effect

Answer (score 2):

Is the Company.CompanyServices property marked as virtual? [Check out ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) on entity framework, where he creates POCO classes with one to many relationships he marks the collection properties as virtual.

When I first started using EF 4, that had me stumped for quite a while.

Obviously I can't see your entity classes so this may be a moot point!

Comment: yeah its virtual - the project is code-first, so no choice there.

Comment: This is the most commonly overlooked issue with EFCF and I must admit I've wasted hours on it myself. If the property is *definitely* virtual, is the relationship mapped properly through the `DbContext` configuration settings?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer that's not wholly inuitive, but it works which is the main thing.

Happy to see one that plays on the original query...

```
var query = (
                    from directorCompany in ctx.CompanyDirectors
                      .Where(d => d.ContactAddress.Contact.Id == contactId)
                    select directorCompany.Company
                  ).OrderBy(c => c.CompanyName).Distinct();
      return query.Include(c => c.CompanyServices).ToList();
```